# Eclipse will automatically import R

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I am developing an android application in Eclipse. Eclipse sometimes imports R automatically so I just click (ctrl + shift + o) to find that import and delete it. But now, every time I delete it, it will bring it back no matter how many times I delete it.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem so I will be able to compile my project?

Comment: I suspect you want the `r.java-file` tag, not `r`. R is an open-source stats and numerical analysis package.

Comment: Please make sure there is no error in xml file, just clean and build the application,then include <your package>.R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was something wrong with my settings. Thanks everyone for there help.

Comment: Please give details on what you changed in your settings to resolve this for the benefit of other people who encounter this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse will try to construct an import statement for related types when you use auto-complete. This is a configurable option which you can disable under Eclipse's preferences dialog `Java -> Editor -> Content Assist "Add import instead of qualified name"` This is not configurable on a per package basis though.

I do wonder, however, what your objection is to importing your resource class. Is it that you just want references to `R` to always be fully qualified? I don't know of any technical reason why this might be preferable. If it's an issue of style, then I'd interject that it might be a misguided preference. Personally, I'd rather not have to regularly read source files that interspersed imported and fully-qualified class names. If your need is neither of these things, perhaps you could share more detail so that we can give you a better answer?

Comment: i am using the sample project Searchable dictionaryand it won't compile. On this line InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions); it will throw an error _R cannot be resolved to a variable_ and I get that error with everything I try to compile. Then I go to my imports and remove import R, and then it comes up again after I save

Comment: Also, it seems that its not generating the R file... -.- this is the error message that im getting:

eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335  
java.version=1.6.0_29  
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.  
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_GB  
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product  
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product  
  
Error  
Wed Jan 25 01:34:42 GMT 2012  
Failed to load properties file for project 'WiktionarySimple'

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and rebuilding? Have you changed any of the settings in the Android plugin that may be preventing R from being generated?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any android.R classes,if yes remove it.
If no try to add your app.R import manually before saving the file.
I know this is annoying but thats how eclipse works for auto import....

you can also try removing automatically import settings from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was automatically added appcompat_v7 in project preferences. I have no idea how and why it is done in eclipse and mostly it causes this problem.

[image]